# ¿Qué ancho debería tener este contenedor?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy construyendo un sitio en Internet y tengo una duda sobre el ancho del elemento `main`.

El código es **el que sigue**:

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

nav {
  background-color: #ff3b30
}

main {
  background-color: #04de71;
  width: 75%
}

footer {
  background-color: #787aff
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>undefined</nav>
  <main>undefined</main>
  <footer>undefined</footer>
</body>
```

Tenemos claro que quiero que `main` ocupe el 75% de la página. El problema reside en que a medida que el viewport tiende a 0, el contenido se va haciendo más slim, y tiene sentido, puesto que `main` está ocupando el 75% del viewport de, por ejemplo, un móvil.

El comportamiento que espero y quiero es que haya espacios a ambos lados de `main` ocupando (100% - 75%) / 2 y que al disminuir el viewport horizontal y llegue un punto en que el width del viewport = width de `main`, este vaya "de la mano" con el viewport.

Todo esto tengo que realizarlo con %, **abstenerse px o medidas relacionadas, así como consultas @media**.

Dejo un ejemplo claro de un [sitio web](https://meyerweb.com/) que sigue el comportamiento que quiero conseguir pero en px. Mi caso **debe ser** con %. El elemento a investigar es `<div id="main"></div>`

Comment: La página a la que haces mención, es la misma que explica cómo funciona, está utilizando la unidad `ch`: https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2018/06/28/what-is-the-css-ch-unit/

Comment: Puede ser una opción, pero estoy intentando realizarlo con %, ¿habrá alguna manera de realizarlo?

Comment: El ejemplo que pones no veo que tenga nada que ver con lo que pides, en esa web el main tiene un ancho máximo, crece con el viewport hasta que llega a ese ancho y entonces deja de crecer. Si quieres comportamientos distintos a distintas resoluciones entonces deberías usar mediaqueries, es para lo que son, no entiendo porque no quieres usarlas

Comment: Como te dije anteriormente, la página usa la unidad `ch` y aunque `main` no usa consultas `@media`, la etiqueta `body` sí que las utiliza en su fuente al darle valores en `em`, esto por consiguiente va a afectar el comportamiento de `main` dependiendo del valor que se de al `width` en `ch`.

Comment: La cosa es que esa consulta `@media` se aplica mucho después de que el `viewport` tenga el mismo `width` que `main`. [GIF](https://i.imgur.com/3Pqyr66.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya te dijeron en los comentarios, no es posible hacerlo en porcentaje, ya que está usando `ch`. En definitiva, el texto del sitio es un %70 (aproximado), luego queda fijado y deja de ser un porcentaje.

Lo que se puede hacer es usar *JavaScript* para transformar el porcentaje inicial en pixeles, y agregar un estilo a partir de eso.

Se intenta generar mediante *JavaScript* algo como lo siguiente:

```
main {
    background-color: #04de71;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Esto, suponiendo que *500px* es el *%75* del ancho de la ventana. Para obtener el ancho, se usa `window.innerWidth`.

La función se inicializa en el `onload` del `body`, pasando como parámetro el *75*, que es el porcentaje:

```
<body onload = "agregar_estilo_ancho(75)" >
```

Código final:

```js
function agregar_estilo_ancho(porcentaje){
  var ancho = Math.floor(window.innerWidth*porcentaje/100)
  var contenido = "main {background-color: #04de71; margin: 0 auto; " +
    "width: " + ancho + "px;}"
  ;
  var estilo = document.createElement("style")
  estilo.innerHTML = contenido
  document.head.appendChild(estilo)
  console.log("Tamaño fijado: " + ancho + " pixeles")
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #012f;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body onload = "agregar_estilo_ancho(75)" >
  <main>Texto</main>
</body>
```

Comment: Exactamente lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 2):

¿Has probado a hacer uso del `display flex`?

Aquí he te he creado un snippet donde haciendo uso de las propiedades de flex `align-items` y `justify-content` he conseguido centrar todo el contenido de un elemento (en este caso del `body`) y luego ya con aplicarle el `width` que desees al hijo te pondrá automáticamente márgenes iguales a los lados

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

main {
  background-color: red;
  width: 75%;
  height: 80%;
}

nav,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
  </nav>
  <main>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Lo he probado, pero lo que necesito es que cuando el viewport disminuya, llegue un punto en que `main` y este viewport tengan el mismo `width`, y a partir de ahí que ambos vayan disminuyendo con el mismo `width`.

Comment: ¿Como tienes configurado el viewport, porque no se si termino de pillarte?
Igual a mayores de mi respuesta puedes jugar con el `max-width` y el `min-width` del `main`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas son media queries para variar los valores que le das a cada clase dependiendo el tamaño de la pantalla (puedes ver un poco más en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/205458/23233)).

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
nav {
  background-color: #ff3b30
}
main {
  background-color: #04de71;
  width: 75%
}
footer {
  background-color: #787aff
}
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
   main {
     width: 80%
   }
}
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 479px) {
   main {
     width: 100%
   }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>undefined</nav>
  <main>undefined</main>
  <footer>undefined</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: No, porque el screen de un iPhone X, por ejemplo, es de 2.436 por 1.125 píxeles. Hacerlo con consultas media añade código innecesario. La página que he indicado en cuestión no utiliza consultas media para realizar lo que quiero, por lo que existe un método mejor de realizar eso.